# Variable looses reference, When the referenced variable later references another

Tags: php, reference, ref

When referencing b=&a; then a=&c. b looses reference with a, but c properly references to a. SO, Why its happening??

I have readed all pages about reference in php.net, but none of it seems to  help me.

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

```
<?php 
$a = 'aVal';
$b = 'bVal';
$c = 'cVal';

$b =&$a;
$a =&$c;

$a = '-a-';
$b = '-b-';
$c = '-c-';

printf("\n\$a = %s;\n\$b = %s;\n\$c = %s;", $a, $b, $c);

?>
```

In this code, `c` is reference to `a`. But Why, `b` lost reference with `a`?

Comment: Try putting your `printf` after each assignment and it should be obvious what is happening. https://3v4l.org/VmTel

Comment: You must always remember that PHP excuting script line by line. While coding with PHP i usually using `var_dump();` and `exit();` to understand data structure